# USB drive might be broken. How to find out for sure?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, hardware, automount

I got this USB drive from my father. It doesn't show up in the GUI anymore and in fact couldn't even get mounted properly.

Below is the dmesg output from the time I plugged in the drive. 
It does show up in the output of `lsusb` and `lshw` but it's not shown with `df -h`.

I don't know what to do anymore. Can you guys point me in the right direction or is it already a lost cause?

```
dmesg:
[  664.332207] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  664.465142] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0740
[  664.465150] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  664.465155] usb 2-1: Product: My Passport 0740
[  664.465159] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  664.465163] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 575844314537314D44534436
[  664.466349] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  664.466614] scsi host10: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  665.464943] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0740 1003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  665.465427] scsi 10:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  665.468951] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  665.469171] ses 10:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[  665.469334] ses 10:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[  673.492303] ses 10:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x8000002
[  673.492312] ses 10:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[  673.496441] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  682.572256] .....................................................................not responding...
[  931.085679] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1111.093707] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1291.101613] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1291.101641] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1291.101646] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current]
[ 1291.101650] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[ 1471.109686] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1471.109714] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 1651.117609] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1651.117662] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1651.117666] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1651.123256] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[ 1651.123265] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current]
[ 1651.123273] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[ 1831.129639] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1831.131261] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 30s
[ 2011.133607] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 2191.141601] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 2191.141636] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2191.141649] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current]
[ 2191.141653] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Internal target failure
[ 2371.149643] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 2551.157634] sd 10:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 2551.157665] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1058:0740 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport

lshw:
 *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: My Passport 0740
                   vendor: Western Digital
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   logical name: scsi10
                   version: 10.03
                   serial: 575844314537314D44534436
                   capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      product: My Passport 0740
                      vendor: WD
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@10:0.0.0
                      logical name: /dev/sdb
                      version: 1003
                      serial: WXD1E71MDSD6
                      configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Comment: Do you get a new entry in `ls /dev` when the device is plugged in? Can you mount that device?

Comment: Search online for the Product description for your "Western Digital My Passport 0740". From the name, I will guess that it wants some sort of authentication before it agrees to be a disk.

Comment: @dan08 /dev/sg2 and /dev/sg3 are new. But can't mount them:
    tyrell@highgarden:~$ sudo mount /dev/sg2 /mnt/usb
    mount:  /dev/sg2 is not a block device

Comment: Can you see it with `gparted` ? `sudo apt-get install gparted`. It is a partition manager, if you can see it, format it.

Comment: no not visible in gparted. It does show up in gnome-disks though. But it only says "no media"

Comment: Well it looks like the USB controller still works, but the drive doesn't spin up. If you feel like DIY you might try to put a new disk into the  housing. As it happens I just had one of those break down, too. A rather new one , even. Maybe WD has some quality issues with that model?

Comment: So no chance to recover the data on the drive?

Comment: @Hinz: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Nattorice: unless you have a dust-free room and a very good grasp of electronics and mechanics: no way to recover the data on the drive (you can send it in to a lab, but that'll cost more money then the drive is worth, and giving you that as an answer, would be off-topic here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On special request from Fabby I'll make my more or less educated guess into an answer:

Well, judging from the dmesg log it looks like the USB controller still works, but the drive doesn't spin up. If you feel like DIY you might try to put a new disk into the housing. As it happens I just had one of those WD passports break down, too. A rather new one, even. Maybe WD has some quality issues with that model?

Another possibility might be to try the drive on a windows PC if you have access to one. Just to make sure. Maybe the Windows driver does something differently.

If you see a device entry in /dev you might have a go with [smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools). Most harddisks keep logs about lots of parameters and errors, using a standard called [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.). That's not for data recovery, mind you, if the drive is broken it won't do you any more good as anythings else. But at least it might be a confirmation if you see suspicious error levels there. Even if it doesn't spin up, maybe the SMART log is still readable.

Finally, off-topic or not, if you absolutely *have* to recover the data on the drive, there are commercial service providers who seem to be able to extract data from almost anything, but that can get really expensive.

Comment: A long time ago, had a WD disk that refused to spin-up after sitting unused for a weekend.  Giving it a sharp rap with the eraser end of a pencil was just enough of a jolt to free it up.  WD did replace it on warranty (had a too thick oxide problem).